# Applications of one-to-one recurrent networks

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks

I'm studying recurrent neural networks. Reading [this page](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/teaching/cs-230/cheatsheet-recurrent-neural-networks) where it lists different types of recurrent network architectures, I think think of applications involving one-to-many (speech/sentence generation), many-to-one (a conventional time-series classification/prediction task) and many-to-many (machine translation). But I can't really think of an application where it's one-to-one. What is one-to-one used for?

[Edit] Note that on the page, it says ``Traditional neural network'' for one-to-one networks. But a traditional neural network would be a feedforward network rather than RNN? [\Edit]

Comment: I don't understand your last remark 'Note that on the page, it says ``Traditional neural network'' for one-to-one networks'. Why are you making this remark? What is your actual question? Are you asking what would be a 1-to-1 application of RNNs?

Comment: Yes to "Are you asking what would be a 1-to-1 application of RNNs". My remark refers to the link (https://stanford.edu/~shervine/teaching/cs-230/cheatsheet-recurrent-neural-networks). In there, they've noted on the side of each architecture type the type of application that will use that architecture. For one-to-one, it just says "traditional neural network". I'm struggling to understand what that's actually referring to.